# Signed but still can't open

Tags: macos, code-signing, gatekeeper

A colleague of mine signed an application we're working on. Trying to open it from finder, I get an error message

> “‹Name›” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

(or the local translation of this). On console I read

```
CoreServicesUIAgent[‹pid›]: Error -60005 creating authorization
```

But if I run codesign on the code, it seems to check out just fine:

```
$ codesign -vv .
.: valid on disk
.: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

So it seems the bundle got signed correctly. To get more details:

```
$ codesign -dvv .
Executable=…
Identifier=…
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=440 flags=0x0(none) hashes=8+3 location=embedded
Signature size=4731
Authority=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: ‹Name› (‹TeamID›)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=21.07.2016, ‹Time›
Info.plist entries=25
TeamIdentifier=‹TeamID›
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=1164
Internal requirements count=1 size=208
```

So from the `Authority=` lines I'd conclude that the certificate chain could be verified as well, and it does lead back to Apple. **How is that “unidentified”?**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27311036/1468366) I learned about `spctl`, but it doesn't provide much information either:

```
$ spctl --assess -vvvv .
.: rejected
origin=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: ‹Name› (‹TeamID›)
```

**How can I get more information as to why *exactly* the app fails to load?**

Answer (score 1):

While formulating the question, I tried various combinations of keywords and eventually found [Difference between “Mac Developer” and “3rd Party Mac Developer Application”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13196291/1468366) on Stack Overflow, which led to developer documentation on [Maintaining Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW42) which in turn writes this:

> - **Type:** Mac App Distribution:
>     **Name:** `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Team Name`
>     **Description:** Used to sign a Mac app before submitting it to the Mac App Store.
> - **Type:** Developer ID Application:
>     **Name:** `Developer ID Application: Team Name`
>     **Description:** Used to sign a Mac app before distributing it outside the Mac App Store.

So apparently this form of code signing is suitable only for submission for the App Store, but not for stand-alone distribution. That took quite a while to work out, so I hope this Q&A will help others avoid that time.